# Want to return value from getshare() function but it is not returning anything. Is there any alternative approach?

Tags: javascript, foreach, return, addeventlistener

```js
const btns = document.querySelector(".col");

const share = Array.from(btns.children);
console.log(share)


let share_percentage = getshare();

function getshare(){
    let share_value;
    share.forEach(btn=>{
        btn.addEventListener("click",function(){
            share.forEach((btn)=>{
                btn.classList.remove("active");
            })
            if(btn.id!="input-share"){
                let btn_value = btn.innerHTML.replace("%","");
                btn.classList.toggle("active");
                share_value = btn_value;
            }
            else{
                btn_value = getinputshare();
                btn.addEventListener("click",function(){
                    btn.classList.toggle("active-input");
                    share_value = btn_value;
                })
            }
            return share_value;
        })
        
    })
}


function getinputshare(){
    return document.getElementById("input-share").value;
}

function getbill(){
    let bill_value = document.getElementById("bill").value;
    return bill_value;
}


function getpeople(){
    let people_value = document.getElementById("people").value;
    return people_value;
}



function tipcalculate(){
    let a = getbill();
    console.log(a);
    let b = share_percentage;
    console.log(b);
    let c = getpeople();
    console.log(c);
    let tip_amount = (a*b)/(100*c);
    console.log(tip_amount)
}

const reset = document.getElementById("reset");

reset.addEventListener("click",function(){
    tipcalculate();
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Tip Spiltter</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/124816636a.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="script.js" defer></script>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@100;300;400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Space+Mono:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>SPLI <br>TTER</h1>
    <div class="main">
        <div class="container-section">

            <div class="container">
                <h4>Bill</h4>
                <input type="number" placeholder="0" id="bill" onblur="getbill()">
                <span>$</span>
            </div>

            <div class="container" id="middle-container">
                <h4>Select Tip %</h4>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col">
                        <button>5%</button>
                        <button>10%</button>
                        <button>15%</button>
                        <button>25%</button>
                        <button>50%</button>
                        <input type="number"  placeholder="Custom" id="input-share" onblur="getinputshare()">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="container">
                <h4>Number of People</h4>
                <input type="number" placeholder="0" id="people" onblur="getpeople()">
                <span id="person"><img src="images/icon-person.svg" alt=""></span>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="calculator">
            <h4>Tip Amount</h4>
            <div class="result">
                <span>/ person</span>
                <h1>$0.00</h1>
            </div>
            <h4>Total</h4>
            <div class="result">
                <span>/ person</span>
                <h1>$0.00</h1>
            </div>

            <button id="reset">RESET</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

To calculate tip I need three values : bill_value , share_value , people_value.
The only problem I am facing is with the share_value. In the tipcalculate() functionit
is not reading its value and giving undefined. I googled and find out that values
cannot be returned from foreach so is there any alternative way by which I can perform
the same operation and get share_value as well.

```
 const btns = document.querySelector(".col");   
 const share = Array.from(btns.children);
 console.log(share)


let share_percentage = getshare();

function getshare(){
    let share_value;
    share.forEach(btn=>{
        btn.addEventListener("click",function(){
            share.forEach((btn)=>{
                btn.classList.remove("active");
            })
            if(btn.id!="input-share"){
                let btn_value = btn.innerHTML.replace("%","");
                btn.classList.toggle("active");
                share_value = btn_value;
            }
            else{
                btn_value = getinputshare();
                btn.addEventListener("click",function(){
                    btn.classList.toggle("active-input");
                    share_value = btn_value;
                })
            }
            return share_value;
        })
        
    })
}


function getinputshare(){
    return document.getElementById("input-share").value;
}

function getbill(){
    let bill_value = document.getElementById("bill").value;
    return bill_value;
}


function getpeople(){
    let people_value = document.getElementById("people").value;
    return people_value;
}



function tipcalculate(){
    let a = getbill();
    console.log(a);
    let b = share_percentage;
    console.log(b);
    let c = getpeople();
    console.log(c);
    let tip_amount = (a*b)/(100*c);
    console.log(tip_amount)
}

const reset = document.getElementById("reset");

reset.addEventListener("click",function(){
    tipcalculate();
})
```

Comment: Do I need to include only html? I don't know what is mvce.

Comment: Sorry that should have been [mcve] using the `[<>]` snippet function. Include the HTML and JS.

Comment: Ok. I have added both html and js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way is to give your buttons a class and values:

```
<div class="col">
  <button value="5" class="percent-btn">5%</button>
  <button value="10" class="percent-btn">10%</button>
  <button value="15" class="percent-btn">15%</button>
  <button value="25" class="percent-btn">25%</button>
  <button value="50" class="percent-btn">50%</button>
  <input type="number" placeholder="Custom" id="input-share" />
</div>
```

Then add an event listener to the whole div. When the click event target is a button save its value to the `share_percentage` variable:

```
let share_percentage

...

const per = document.querySelector('.col')
per.addEventListener('click', e => {
  if (e.target.tagName == 'BUTTON') {
    percentBtns.forEach(b => b.classList.remove('active'))
    e.target.classList.add('active')
    share_percentage = e.target.value
    customPercent.value = '' // clear the custom percent value
  }
})
```

And for the custom tip percentage input add a [change](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event) event listener to it. Here I am making it save its value to `share_percentage` and remove the `active` class from other percentage buttons.

```
const customPercent = document.getElementById('input-share')
customPercent.addEventListener('change', () => {
  percentBtns.forEach(b => b.classList.remove('active'))
  share_percentage = customPercent.value

  // do more stuff
})
```

Here is a working example with the relevant parts:

```js
const percentBtns = [...document.querySelectorAll('.percent-btn')]
let share_percentage

const per = document.querySelector('.col')
per.addEventListener('click', e => {
  if (e.target.tagName == 'BUTTON') {
    percentBtns.forEach(b => b.classList.remove('active'))
    e.target.classList.add('active')
    share_percentage = e.target.value
    customPercent.value = ''
  }
})

const customPercent = document.getElementById('input-share')
customPercent.addEventListener('change', () => {
  percentBtns.forEach(b => b.classList.remove('active'))
  share_percentage = customPercent.value

  // do more stuff
})

function getbill() {
  return document.getElementById('bill').value
}

function getpeople() {
  return document.getElementById('people').value
}

function tipcalculate() {
  let a = getbill()
  console.log('getbill() = ', a)
  let b = share_percentage
  console.log('share_percentage = ', b)
  let c = getpeople()
  console.log('getpeople() = ', c)
  let tip_amount = (a * b) / (100 * c)
  console.log('tip_amount = ', tip_amount)
  return tip_amount
}

const reset = document.getElementById('reset')

reset.addEventListener('click', function() {
  console.clear()
  tipcalculate()
})
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.box {
  margin: 0 10px 7px 10px;
  padding: 0 4px;
}

.active {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <h5>Bill</h5>
  <input type="number" placeholder="0" id="bill" onblur="getbill()" />
  <span>$</span>
</div>

<div class="box">
  <h5>Select Tip %</h5>
  <div class="col">
    <button value="5" class="percent-btn">5%</button>
    <button value="10" class="percent-btn">10%</button>
    <button value="15" class="percent-btn">15%</button>
    <button value="25" class="percent-btn">25%</button>
    <button value="50" class="percent-btn">50%</button>
    <input type="number" placeholder="Custom" id="input-share" />
  </div>
</div>

<div class="box">
  <h5>Number of People</h5>
  <input type="number" placeholder="0" id="people" />
  <button id="reset">Calculate Tip</button>
</div>
```

Comment: If you please can tell me where I was going wrong in fetching the share_percentage value.

Comment: @ParasSharma The `share_percentage` was being Immediately set to the return value of `getshare()` which is not even returning anything and it was just adding event listeners to the buttons. If you instead updated the value of `share_percentage` directly inside the event listeners the buttons might have worked but the custom tip input might have needed to be fixed.